# Automatically import data into excel from Google sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I use the importrange feature to import data from one Google sheet workbook to another. Does anybody know if it's possible to import and populate a cell from a Google sheet workbook cell into an excel cell using import external data feature or something like the Google sheets importrange feature?

Answer (score 0):

If your Excel files are in your computer, seems the Rajesh S answer is the best. But if your files are on the cloud, you can use add-ons for Google Sheets to create this "live stream" from the Google Sheets to Excel files, even if the files are closed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following VBA code to import Google Sheet into Excel.

```
Sub importGSheet()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add("URL;https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ah4Bis8FTYfCdDJILVdYOG1EZEYtc1N3NF96dHZSYkE&usp=sharing#gid=0", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .WebTables = "2"
        .Refresh False
    End With

End Sub
```

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: Write your concern to down vote !!

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you, but the code just didn't work for my google sheet (it imported _something_, but not the data on my sheet) and your answer doesn't make it clear when it's supposed or not supposed to work

Comment: This worked for me though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35802503/1026

Comment: @Nickolay, thanks for feed back ,, could you please write what error you have received , help me to fix it.

Comment: Didn't get an error, the imported data had a warning about Google Finance tickers(?!) followed by a few cells of the first row of the spreadsheet...

Comment: Reposted from a non-answer originally posted by COW: *I tried Rajesh S's code and replaced the URL with the URL of my workbook, but it wasn't working as expected (it imported an advert and just the sheet names from my Google Sheet, however, the code worked for me after I updated the destination range to match the size of my Google Sheet and I changed the "webtables" line to: << .WebTables = "1" >*