# Import data into excel from Google sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, import

I was looking for information about importing data from GS to excel and found [this code](https://superuser.com/questions/1289323/automatically-import-data-into-excel-from-google-sheets)

```
Sub importGSheet()
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add("URL;https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ah4Bis8FTYfCdDJILVdYOG1EZEYtc1N3NF96dHZSYkE&usp=sharing#gid=0", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .WebTables = "2"
    .Refresh False
End With
```

End Sub

provided by Rajesh S.

After changing

```
.WebTables = "2"
```

to

```
.WebTables = "1"
```

it works, except for some special characters from my alphabet (for example instead of "Č" it shows "─î"), that not imports correctly. Is there a way to set the code to correctly import these special characters?

Comment: Do you have those fonts installed on your machine too?

Comment: Yes, I use fonts with these characters every day... I guess it has something to do with the code table, but just don't know how to set the right code table when importing the data.